# Get "latest" row after GROUP BY over multiple tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, postgresql-9.1, rails-postgresql

I'd preferably like to first query listed below and just group by `stories.id`, but I get the  following error:

`ERROR:  column "u.first_name" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function LINE 1: SELECT "s".*, "u"."first_name", "u"."last_name", ("i"."filen...`

The second query works but does not group by `stories.id` and generates the wrong results. Is it possible to select from multiple tables and not group by all of them?

The table `panels` also has a column `updated_at`. I would like to get the newest `file` per story according to `panels.updated_at`.

```
   SELECT 
        "s".*, 
        "u"."first_name", 
        "u"."last_name", 
        ("i"."filename" || '.' || "i"."extension") AS "file" 
    FROM 
        "stories" "s" 
    LEFT JOIN "panels" "p" ON("p"."story_id" = "s"."id") 
    LEFT JOIN "users" "u" ON("s"."user_id" = "u"."uid")
    LEFT JOIN "images" "i" ON ("p"."image_id" = "i"."id") 
    WHERE 
        "s"."complete" = false AND 
        "s"."created_by" = 205700489 
    GROUP BY 
        "s"."id", 
    ORDER BY 
        "s"."created_at" DESC
```

---

```
   SELECT 
        "s".*, 
        "u"."first_name", 
        "u"."last_name", 
        ("i"."filename" || '.' || "i"."extension") AS "file" 
    FROM 
        "stories" "s" 
    LEFT JOIN "panels" "p" ON("p"."story_id" = "s"."id") 
    LEFT JOIN "users" "u" ON("s"."user_id" = "u"."uid")
    LEFT JOIN "images" "i" ON ("p"."image_id" = "i"."id") 
    WHERE 
        "s"."complete" = false AND 
        "s"."created_by" = 205700489 
    GROUP BY 
        "s"."id", 
        "u"."first_name", 
        "u"."last_name", "i"."filename", 
        "i"."extension" 
    ORDER BY 
        "s"."created_at" DESC
```

Comment: How is the result of the second query wrong?

Comment: @Igor Romanchenko It does not group by story id

Comment: Your question is inconclusive. If you want to group by `story.id`, you *have* to define what to do pick from multiple rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated after clarification of the question:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (s.created_at, s.id)
       s.*
      ,u.first_name
      ,u.last_name
      ,concat_ws('.', i.filename, i.extension) AS file
FROM   stories s 
LEFT   JOIN users  u ON u.uid = s.user_id
LEFT   JOIN panels p ON p.story_id = s.id
LEFT   JOIN images i ON i.id = p.image_id
WHERE  s.complete = false
AND    s.created_by = 205700489 
ORDER  BY s.created_at DESC, s.id, p.updated_at DESC;
```

[Grouping by primary key](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/release-9-1.html#AEN112891) requires PostgreSQL 9.1.
I use [`concat_ws()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER), because I don't know which columns might be `NULL`. If both `i.filename` and `i.extension` are defined `NOT NULL`, you can simplify.

Effect of the additional `ORDER BY` item `p.updated_at DESC` is that the "newest" `file` will be picked per story. The query technique is explained in full under this related question:
[Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/sql-select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group)

Comment: This query works okey except I get a list of files `97799.jpg, 5234.jpg` what I'm really looking for is the last file panels has an order and created by column and I'd need only the newest.

Comment: @stefan: You need to edit your question and put all the information there. This is a public forum and a question should paint a complete picture. Comments are simply not good enough. Use `edit` right under your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like:

```
   SELECT 
        "s".*, 
        (SELECT "u"."first_name" 
         FROM "users" "u"
         WHERE "s"."user_id" = "u"."uid"
         LIMIT 1) , 
        (SELECT "u"."last_name" 
         FROM "users" "u"
         WHERE "s"."user_id" = "u"."uid"
         LIMIT 1), 
        (SELECT "i"."filename" || '.' || "i"."extension"
         FROM "panels" "p" 
         JOIN "images" "i" ON ("p"."image_id" = "i"."id")
         WHERE "p"."story_id" = "s"."id" 
         LIMIT 1) AS "file" 
    FROM 
        "stories" "s" 
    WHERE 
        "s"."complete" = false AND 
        "s"."created_by" = 205700489 
    ORDER BY 
        "s"."created_at" DESC
```

It will get only 1 record from `"users"` and `"panels" JOIN "images"` per record in `"stories"` .

Add `ORDER BY`, extra `WHERE` or some aggregates to get what you need from `"users"` and `"panels" JOIN "images"`

UPD Also, you can use something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT ON ("s"."id") 
    "s".*, 
    "u"."first_name", 
    "u"."last_name", 
    ("i"."filename" || '.' || "i"."extension") AS "file" 
FROM 
    "stories" "s" 
LEFT JOIN "panels" "p" ON("p"."story_id" = "s"."id") 
LEFT JOIN "users" "u" ON("s"."user_id" = "u"."uid")
LEFT JOIN "images" "i" ON ("p"."image_id" = "i"."id") 
WHERE 
    "s"."complete" = false AND 
    "s"."created_by" = 205700489 
ORDER BY 
    "s"."id"
) t ORDER BY "t"."created_at" DESC
```

It will leave only one row for every distinct `"s"."id"`

Comment: Is there a performance difference in using so many sub selects?

Comment: @stefan Most of the time postgres will optimize the query, so there wont be much performance difference.

Comment: @stefan: Generally, correlated subqueries are an anti-pattern for performance. Avoid them if you can. But as @Igor mentioned, Postgres can optimize the query plan under favorable conditions. Test your queries with [`EXPLAIN ANALYZE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-explain.html) and compare to get definitive answers. Run multiple times to exclude caching effects.